# Erro: ValueFactory tentou acessar a propriedade Value desta instância

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

Toda vez que crio qualquer projeto *Xamarin* no *Visual Studio 2017* é exibido o seguinte erro ao executar a aplicação:

```
Erro: ValueFactory tentou acessar a propriedade Value dessa instância.
```

Por quê acontece este erro? O que devo fazer para solucionar?

Comment: Você cria o projeto e não modificada nada, e o erro ocorre, é isso? Ou você tentou fazer alguma modificação no código?

Comment: Sem um contexto limitado as possíbilidades são muito amplas. Se for o caso de dar erro em um _projeto nu_ é provável que seja um problema com os templates do projeto, algum erro ou omissão na instalação ou um problema de atualização dos pacotes ou do xamarin.... é difícil dizer

Comment: @perozzo, isso ocorre ao criar um novo projeto e executa-lo sem realizar alterações.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza a instalação está correta pois funcionou previamente. eu notei que este problema ocorre quando eu já estou com um projeto aberto e desejo criar um novo... Se eu fechar o VS e abrir o ultimo projeto criado é compilado normalmente...

Comment: Pode ser que tenha identificado um bug no Visual Studio então, já que identificou o que exatamente deve-se fazer para gerar o erro.

Comment: E se você abrir o visual studio 'em branco', criar um novo projeto e executar ele funciona normal?

Comment: Se abrir o VS e criar um novo projeto em branco é executado. Agora se eu fechar esse projeto e criar um novo projeto em branco dá este erro ao executar.

Comment: To com o @perozzo. Acho que bug do VS mesmo. Tem outros parecidos: por exemplo, se você abrir duas soluções em instâncias diferentes do VS ele não executa corretamente, os caches das `bin` e `obj`, as necessidades de clean/rebuild e por aí. Acho que há um pouco de ambiente nisso também, não é em todos os computadores que acontece... difícil de diagnosticar mesmo =/ mas não acho que seja um erro de programação no qual possamos ajudar, por isso ,mesmo tendo dado +1, estou sinalizando a pergunta para atenção dos revisores.

Comment: Dei up vote na pergunta. Além dos bugs que o @DiegoRafaelSouza citou, se tu abrir o Android Studio ao mesmo tempo que o Visual Studio, além de não identificar mais o dispositivo físico conectado por USB, erros estranhos de build ocorrem. Poderia aproveitar que descobriu mais um bug e reportar para o VS.

Comment: Eu vou reportar, provavélmente mais pessoas estão passando por este problema... quem sabe em um proximo update estes erros sejam corrijidos

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro geralmente ocorre quando há um problema com uma instância de Lazy em seu código. A propriedade Value da instância é acessada antes que o valor seja carregado.

Uma solução para resolver este erro é garantir que a instância de Lazy tenha seu valor carregado antes de acessar a propriedade Value. Você pode fazer isso chamando o método Value da instância Lazy. Por exemplo, em vez de acessar a propriedade Value diretamente, você pode fazer algo como:

```
Lazy<T> lazy = new Lazy<T>();
// ...
T valor = lazy.Value; // Carrega o valor antes de acessar a propriedade
```

Outra possibilidade é que o problema esteja relacionado a uma configuração incorreta do seu projeto Xamarin. Você pode tentar verificar se todas as dependências estão corretamente configuradas e se o pacote NuGet do Xamarin.Forms está atualizado.

Se o problema persistir, tente criar um novo projeto Xamarin a partir do modelo padrão e verifique se o erro ainda ocorre. Se isso resolver o problema, pode haver um problema com a configuração do seu projeto atual. Nesse caso, você pode tentar comparar as configurações do projeto atual com as configurações do novo projeto para identificar possíveis diferenças.